# Sort character vector based on another vector

Tags: r, string

I would like to sort one Column1 and Column2 simultaneously

**Data**

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| italy, france, antarctica, brazil | warm, cold, cold, warm |
| kenya, canada, spain, russia, japan | warm, cold, warm, cold, cold |

**Expected result**

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| antarctica, brazil, france, italy | cold, warm, cold, warm |
| canada, japan, kenya, russia, spain | cold, cold, warm, cold, warm |

I have tried `mixedorder()` for Column1 and it works but I don't know how to sort the second column based on first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split `Column1` and `Column2` on comma into new rows, `arrange` the values and summarise the sorted rows again.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(Column1, Column2, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  arrange(row, Column1, Column2) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(across(c(Column1, Column2), toString)) %>%
  select(-row) -> result

result

#  Column1                             Column2                     
#  <chr>                               <chr>                       
#1 antarctica, brazil, france, italy   cold, warm, cold, warm      
#2 canada, japan, kenya, russia, spain cold, cold, warm, cold, warm
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Column1 = c("italy, france, antarctica, brazil", 
"kenya, canada, spain, russia, japan"), Column2 = c("warm, cold, cold, warm", 
"warm, cold, warm, cold, cold")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution ! I will try and implement this solution on a larger dataframe with many more columns. Really appreciate your solution using dplyr since I love that package !!

Answer (score 2):

Use `order(column 1)` (replacing column 1 with your data) to get a vector with sorted order and use this to order both. If it is a `data.frame` it becomes

```r
df[order(df$"column 1"),]
```

Again replacing `df` and `"column 1"` with the appropriate names.

Comment: Thanks I tried it but did not get a resolution, but thanks for your time.